# Laravel Voyager customize browse.blade.php

Tags: php, laravel, voyager

New to Laravel/Voyager. I have overridden the Voyager Controller and View as mentioned in the [documentation](https://voyager-docs.devdojo.com/customization/overriding-files). Need to customize the `browse.blade.php` to show data from the joined table also. The first part was easy, added

```
$query->join('table_b', 'table_a.id', '=', 'table_b.table_a_id');
```

in the overridden `VoyagerBaseController` controller `index(..)` method, and can see the altered query by running

```
$query->toSql();
```

However, can't find the `table_b` data in `$dataType->browseRows` in the `browse.blade.php`.

It seems that I'm missing a step in this process.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the `table_b` data stored in the `$dataTypeContent` variable. The `$dataType` variable gets data from the `DataType` model:

```
$slug = $this->getSlug($request);
$dataType = Voyager::model('DataType')->where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();
```

So, to solve my problem I'm getting the "dataType" for my `table_b` also:

```
$additionalSlug = 'table_b'; // for example
$additionalDataType = Voyager::model('DataType')->where('slug', '=', $additionalSlug)->first();
```

Then merging the two "dataTypes" "browseRows" using the `merge()` method:

```
$dataTypeBrowseRows = $dataType->browseRows->merge($additionalDataType->browseRows);
```

After that replacing `@foreach($dataType->browseRows as $row)` with `@foreach($dataTypeBrowseRows as $row)` in the overridden `browse.blade.php` file.

Hope this will help someone.